# Why is the var checker undefined?

Tags: javascript

I dont understand why checker is undefined (thus not fulfilling either condition ===0 or ==1).

It seemed to work in the JS Fiddle without the ready function around it, but it does not work on the live system.

```
var checker = 0;
$(window).ready(function () {



function wertelesen() {



    alert(checker);

    if ($("#ersterstatus").html() == '1') {
        if (checker === 0) {
            alert(checker);
            var currentTime = new Date();
            var hours = currentTime.getHours();
            var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
            var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

            if (minutes < 10) {
                minutes = "0" + minutes;
            }
            if (seconds < 10) {
                seconds = "0" + seconds;
            }

            $("#status1time").html(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
            var checker = 1;
        }

        $("#sd1").html('<img src="img/Status01.png" alt="Status aktiv" class="statusleuchte">');
    }

    if ($("#ersterstatus").html() == '0') {
        if (checker === 1) {
            alert(checker);
            var currentTime = new Date();
            var hours = currentTime.getHours();
            var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
            var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

            if (minutes < 10) {
                minutes = "0" + minutes;
            }
            if (seconds < 10) {
                seconds = "0" + seconds;
            }

            $("#status1time").html(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
            var checker = 0;
        }

        $("#sd1").html('<img src="img/Status00.png" alt="Status inaktiv" class="statusleuchte">');
    }

    setTimeout(wertelesen, 1000);
}
setTimeout(wertelesen, 1000);

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are re-declaring `checker` from a global to a local scope:

```
$("#status1time").html(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
var checker = 1;
```

Just change this to:

```
$("#status1time").html(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
checker = 1;
```

And as pointed out, you're doing this twice too:

```
$("#status1time").html(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
var checker = 0;
```

Comment: There are actually two faulty lines... Just mentioning it so that the OP doesn't miss it.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici Correct, added to answer for clarity

Comment: Yea, I noticed that too the second I posted it. I took those out in the fiddle already. Thats why it worked there.